# BodyEditorLoader.jar gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I was just starting to use the BodyEditorLoader.jar library but i got a NoSuchMethodError without any reason. Then i googled it and found a post on stackoverflow which wasn't useful and links were also broken but i came to know that the official library out there is buggy.

How do i fix this? Could not found the updated version of the library. Also some people provided the updated java file but how do i make it a library file as the library file contains the .class file and not the .java file.

Anyways here is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse
```

and here is the code that gives the error:

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/test.json"));
```

Comment: This means you are using an incompatible combination of libraries. Make sure all the libraries (JAR files) that you are using are the right versions. Look in the docs to find out what the version requirements are.

Comment: @Jesper But there is no mention of the requirements or anything like that in the official website of the library.

Comment: Did you try to search Google with "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse"? You'll find that you're not the first one who gets this error. Seems to be an issue in libgdx. Are you using the latest version of libgdx?

Comment: What is the need of `.class` file if you have bug free `.java` file, keep it your src and treat as your own Java file similar to all other Java file that you have.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan yeah i tried that too but it gives me a lot of errors, which got me thinking that i should probably somehow include it in my library but now that you have mentioned it is ok to do so i think the file that i found on internet is buggy too.

Comment: @Jesper Could not find any help on the internet so far.

Comment: Question looks confusing `bodyeditor-loader.jar` is different from `physics-body-editor.jar`.  `bodyeditor-loader.jar` has single .java file having name `BodyEditorLoader.java`, that having some bug.

Comment: In general they were referring to it as physicsbodyeditor but anyways i edited as i have a problem with bodyeditorloader.jar indeed and not the physicsbodyeditor. So, any solution abhishek?

Answer (score 1):

From question it's seems you have some buggy `BodyEditorLoader` class, you can inject `gdx-utils` jar inside your core module and after that you can access `BodyEditorLoader` class inside your project, May be it solve your problem.

```
dependencies {
     compile group: 'com.github.itsabhiaryan', name: 'gdx-utils', version: '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Don't forget to refresh all of your gradle module.